# how to connect flutterflow with java code?

Tags: java, flutter, android-studio, flutterflow

i wanted to create face recognition mobile app and made interface from flutterflow, and found code with face recognition on java, but i dont know how to connect them. i never code on java before and never used android studio. hope you'll help me. thanks!

i tried to find answer from everywhere, but i didnt found what i needed